# Is Vivien of the Wilds + Wilderness Reclamation a competitive combo?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Vivien, Champion of the Wilds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVivien%2c%20Champion%20of%20the%20Wilds%5d) is a new planeswalker which allows casting creatures with instant speed. I want to combine it with [Wilderness Reclamation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWilderness%20Reclamation%5d) to be able to double my mana during my end step and cast a giant [Hydroid Krasis](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHydroid%20Krasis%5d).  The best case scenario for the deck is:

- turn 1 - [Llanowar Elves](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLlanowar%20Elves%5d)
- turn 2 - [Incubation Druid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIncubation%20Druid%5d)
- turn 3 - [Vivien, Champion of the Wilds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVivien%2c%20Champion%20of%20the%20Wilds%5d)
- turn 4 - [Wilderness Reclamation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWilderness%20Reclamation%5d) + adapt the Incubation Druid
- turn 5 - Cast a 12/12 [Hydroid Krasis](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHydroid%20Krasis%5d) during the endstep

Will it be competitive in Standard?

Also adding a biogenic ooze and simic ascendancy may win you a game. Maybe also add hadanas climb?

Comment: Any combo deck looks good "on paper" (pun intentional) if it hits all its draws and doesn't have to fight any disruption. What's your plan if you don't but all your draws and/or any of your pieces get countered?

Comment: I'd advise you to build the deck, test and modify. I'm pretty sure you'll end up cutting the Viviens though.

Comment: Wilderness Reclamation does not double your mana, it just untaps your lands during other players upkeep.

Comment: Wilderness Reclamation can *effectively* double your mana during your end step, because it untaps all of your lands, so you can tap each land twice during that end step.

Comment: Can you tap the lands at the beginning of the end step? It is at **the beginning** NOT **during**.

Comment: @aslum yes you can

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me start by saying this is a really cool idea, and it may be a very fun deck to play in casual format.  Alternatively, you could add this combo to an existing competitive deck that is already leveraging pieces of this combo in other ways (there is at least one suggestion in the comments).

However, this combo on its own is very unlikely to be competitive in standard given how many pieces you need for it to go off.  It's a three card combo at it's heart (Vivien + Wilderness Reclimation + Krasis) that also requires mana acceleration to go off on a reasonable timeframe.  The best-case you present is a turn 7 win, and your whole first 5 turns were spent setting it up, leaving you little buffer to react to your opponent or handle disruption.  On top of that, your plan is very brittle; most combos are vulnerable to control, but yours is also vulnerable to burn and aggro due to many of your key mana sources being creatures and one of your key cards being a planeswalker.

Compare your combo to [Carnage Tyrant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCarnage%20Tyrant%5d) + [Blanchwood Armor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlanchwood%20Armor%5d), which requires a similar mana base.  This creates a similar sized beater on a similar timeframe.  However, it has several advantages:

1. Carnage Tyrant is resistant to both control and burn
2. You can still win with Carnage Tyrant even if you don't draw Blanchwood Armor
3. It's mono-green, meaning you don't need a complex mana base and can't get color-screwed
4. You can do other things in your early turns, like [Commune With Dinosaurs](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCommune%20With%20Dinosaurs%5d) to help set you up or [Vine Mare](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVine%20Mare%5d) to defend you from an aggro deck or start an early offense against a control deck.

That is not to say Hydroid Krasis is worse than Carnage Tyrant.  In fact, Krasis is a competitive card in the current standard, but it tends to find its home in control decks rather than combo, especially since card advantage is a big focus of control and Krasis doubles as card advantage and a finisher.

Another thing to notice about decks that use Krasis in the current meta is that (aside from Llanowar Elves) they tend to focus on creatures with the "Explore" ability rather than creatures that tap directly for mana.  While Explore is slower in terms of mana ramp, it is more resilient as it is still relying on land-based mana, and it lets you do a bit of deck filtering/thinning as well.  In your case in particular, you want land mana rather than creature mana because Wilderness Reclamation only untaps lands.

Comment: thank you guys i appreciate all of your answers.i just wanted to create a cool deck but i guess it wont work :(

Comment: @SharaShara It may very well work as a fun deck to play with your friends.  Casual and tournament environments are very different.

Comment: One other thing to consider is that this combo isn't in isolation; you have the rest of the deck to work with.  So, depending on the rest of this deck, this combo might just be a small part that fits in.

Comment: I think this "combo" would work fairly well within the existing Sultai deck, that run Krasis and Reclamation already.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees With how many creatures? I think Vivien needs more creatures that benefit from flash. Or did you mean the Tyrant / Armor thing?

Answer (score 4):

Hydroid Krasis is already played in some variants of the relatively popular Wilderness Reclamation deck. Being able to create a large creature, gain some life, draw cards **and then immediately have access to the cards thanks to your refreshed mana pool** is a genuinely powerful effect.

Your main issue with this combo is just the inclusion of Vivien, who doesn't have a lot to do in a deck without very many non-flash creatures. You find yourself in sort of a catch-22 here; Vivien's main purposes are to dig for creatures and give them flash, so she works well in a deck with a high density of creatures without flash.

Unfortunately on draws wherein you don't draw or can't protect Vivien, your reclamation won't synergize very well with non-flash creatures. Similarly, Vivien loses value if most of your creatures already have flash. If there are cheaper or more flexible ways to give creatures flash in the format, that may be worth looking into!

Comment: I think it's not really accurate to say Krasis is played in current Wilderness Reclamation decks. It's played alright, but generally as a win condition and not a value creature; the deck doesn't want to cast Krasis unless it's already locked the game up with Nexus.

Answer (score 2):

**Nobody knows**, and nobody will know until we can actually playtest it.

That said I'll say my first impressions are that it's unlikely, because your cards don't work well together:

- Vivien gives your creatures flash, which usually isn't particularly strong with creatures (see [Raff Capashen, Ship's Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRaff%5d%2b%5bCapashen%2c%5d%2b%5bShip%27s%5d%2b%5bMage%5d), which sees no play).
- Because creatures are usually sorcery-speed, Wilderness Reclamation does not synergize unless you also have Vivien in play. This is the reason why current Wilderness Reclamation decks are generally loaded with instants or at least instant-speed mana sinks.

In other words you have subpar cards unless you also have the other card. Vivien is likely to be acceptable even if you don't have Wilderness Reclamation (its two activatable abilities are decent), but Wilderness Reclamation is likely to be a do-nothing.

Finally there is also this:

- Even if you pull the combo off, you might not win. The really strong combos result in a practically won game (e.g. when Standard's current premier combo deck - Nexus - goes off, the opponent never gets another turn, which makes it really hard to lose). In this case you make a 12/12 Krasis that's fully vulnerable to enemy removal. Gaining six life helps, but if you are well behind on the board (which is the biggest weakness of Nexus decks right now) it might not be sufficient. Opponent could easily play something like [Conclave Tribunal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bConclave%20Tribunal%5d) and attack you for 10+ damage.

You could certainly try, but offhand I don't think it'll be worth it.